# Resolution simulation within website with PHP

Tags: javascript, php, css, html

I have pretty strange question. Is there any way to simulate resolution in PHP/javascript? Lets say, my current resolution of screen is 1280x800. I have a container which is 50% width of web page, within it,  I would like to be able to see, how something looks like in diferent resolution, lets say, on 1600x900 laptop screen. It should be shown only within that container. Is it possible? how it can be accomplished?

Comment: On Google Chrome, if you open the developer tools, you can do that

Comment: Thing is, I would like to have it visible on website it-self

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use css [`zoom`](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/z/zoom/)

Css

```
.r100_50 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #A00;
}
```

Html

```
<div class="r100_50">
  This is 100 x 50
</div>
<div class="r100_50" style="zoom: 0.25">
  This is 100 x 50 x 0.25
</div>
<div class="r100_50" style="zoom: 2">
  This is 100 x 50 x 2
</div>
```

[jsFiddle (zoom)](https://jsfiddle.net/Ley3hLdy/)

**EDIT**: Another (better) way is to use [css transformation, scale](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/t/transform/) as pointed out by Justinas.

[jsFiddle (transform)](https://jsfiddle.net/Ley3hLdy/1/)

Comment: **Zoom is an old IE thing. It isn't something you should use on live sites. If you want to scale content, use CSS Transforms** - Your provided jsFiddle is not working.

Comment: Well, jsFiddle works in chrome, not in Firefox as I've just found out ... but yes, transformation would be more suitable ...

Comment: Thanks for Quick answer!